# Office365 Guest Access to Shared Mailbox

Tags: office365

Is it possible for a guest account that exists on 365 to have access to a shared mailbox? Can this be done using B2B collaboration?

I have am unable to find an exact answer from the Microsoft docs on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible.

> The permissions can be set up only within the current organization tenant. It is not possible to set up mailbox permissions with out of tenant users

Source: [Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/add-users/give-mailbox-permissions-to-another-user)